# How to keep an class object stay alive all the time for Web App?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, encryption

I have written an RSA class for my web app which generates keypair to handle the encryption and decryption, its pseudo codes are here:

```
public class RSAFunc {
  private static String CryptMode = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";
  private static KeyPair kp;
  private static KeyPairGenerator kpg;
  private static RSAPrivateKey privKey;
  private static RSAPublicKey pubkey;

  public RSAFunc() {
    // generate specified length of keypair and store the public and private key
  }


  public String decryptMsg(String msg) {
    // decrypt RSA encrypted message
  }


  public String encryptMsg(String msg) {
    // encrypt message with RSA
  }


  public String getPubKey() {
    // return public key as string
  }
}
```

But when I installed this WAR on my server, I figured that I always get different public key at each session, which mean I cannot decrypt my message because the key is wrong.

Is there any way to keep objects or variables to always stay alive until my web application server shutting down?

Comment: You can also use keystore to save your public key. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Singleton design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). This way, you will be able to use same object throughout your application.

You can also use `final` modifier which will ensure that `pubkey` and other variables would be set only once.

Your RSAFunc class can be as follows:

```
public class RSAFunc {

    private static RSAFunc instance = null;

    private final String CryptMode = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";
    private final KeyPair kp;
    private final KeyPairGenerator kpg;
    private final Key privKey;
    private final RSAPublicKey pubkey;

    private RSAFunc() {
        // generate specified length of keypair and store the public and private key
    }

    public static synchronized RSAFunc getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new RSAFunc();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public String decryptMsg(String msg) {
        // decrypt RSA encrypted message
    }

    public String encryptMsg(String msg) {
        // encrypt message with RSA
    }

    public String getPubKey() {
        // return public key as string
    }
}
```

When you need RSAFunc object, instead of `new RSAFunc()`, call `RSAFunc.getInstance()`.

Comment: OOOOOHHHHHH! FINALLY GOT THIS PROBLEM SOLVED! NICE SINGLETON WAY!